# Could we add tags for domain-specific language questions, such as programming?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed several questions that are specific to the domain of computer programming. For example:

- ["bound" or "bonded"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/bound-or-bonded/)
- [Marking plural of code words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4885/marking-plural-of-code-words)

I'd find it useful to tag these sort of questions with a **programming** tag, since I have a special interest in answering them and reading others' answers.

I think other people would also appreciate domain-specific tags, and I'm interested to hear what others think.

Comment: Such tags would certainly be more useful than "usage" or "grammar"...

Comment: Alright. I'm just going to start using those sort of tags if no one has any objection.

Comment: Having a "programming" tag would certainly help me in promoting the site in [my user profile on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/58792/regdwight) and on other programming-related SE sites. The recently created "mathematics" tag, even though it contains just one question right now, probably makes sense in the long run, too. Generally speaking, since questions are allowed to have up to 5 tags, but most of ours have much less (fewer) than that, I suppose it won't *hurt* to have a few domain-specific tags in addition to the ones we already have.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, use a tag for the domain (programming, medicine, law, etc.) This is what some dictionaries do to specify that a particular word is specific to a particular subject domain. It works for me for questions.

Answer (score -1):

No; questions about domain-specific languages mostly belong on SO. ;-P

Comment: I don't think the OP is referring to programming languages that are domain specific and questions about that programming language. Rather I think they are asking about, in general, language from a specific domain, talking -about- programming say. That is, the OP is not concerned about the difference between 'implements' and 'extends' as keywords in Java, but about how to talk in English about the technical language (see the exxamples given).